# one-way interaction between visualisations

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple (one table) report with the following columns: Date, Amount, Category and Subcategory.

I try to create a page with three visualisations.
The first one is for the amount/date (vertical bar chart). The second one is for amount/categories (treemap). The last one is for amount/subcategories (treemap).

I have created hierarchy for date and categories.

When I select a column in the amount/date, the visualisation of the bottom ones filters OK.

The problem that I have is that when I click on the amount/category treemap the amount/date bar chart resets its selection and the amount/category shows all the categories across all the dates.

I have tried to prevent this by setting the interaction to "No Impact" on the amount/date visual, but it didn't help.

How do I create "One Way" interaction between visuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click, you can make multiple selections. If you click normally, then regular visuals will replace filters on other visuals.

Slicers are a special visual type whose selections don't get overridden by selections in other visuals.